# Selecting by character strings from field using ArcGIS / R bridge

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap, r

I am attempting to use the ArcGIS / R bridge R package "arcgisbinding" in order to do the following:

I am trying to select features in a map layer based on textual matches, and I thought that I might be able to use the R bridge to do this. I would like to identify certain features using regular expressions and grepping and then delete these features from the arc.data data frame I have loaded in R, and then save this modified feature class as my new data.

However, when I try to run any functions on the arc.data data.frame, its class changes to something else. I am afraid that I am not able to then convert it into arc.data into a geodatabase.

Do you have any suggestions for searching / manipulating character fields in a feature class using R? Or is this something that the R bridge wasn’t intended for? Are there easy ways to do this in ArcMap? The field I am trying to search is a messy character field (tags from imported OSM data).